# Why I am getting "The method stringToValue(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject" in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am trying to convert message using below code:

**`String message = (String) JSONObject.stringToValue(record.value().toString());`**

and getting below error when using springboot version is 2.4.4 but it is working fine in below versions .

`Error = The method stringToValue(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject`

Below is maven dependency using for above conversion:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
```

can anyone please suggest on this?

Comment: Are you sure that the `JSONObject` is from `org.json` in the scenario where error is occuring?

Comment: yes @GauthamM.. this is import - import org.json.JSONObject;

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest switching to gson instead. It way easier converting to string in gson

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

The code to retrieve a value from Json as String

```
record.get("id").getAsString()
```

Comment: your suggestion is not matching to my requirement. @Tapan

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to call `stringToValue` if the thing you're converting is already a string.

But to answer your question, you should put your mouse on the name JSONObject in your code and get Eclipse to take you to its definition, using ctrl+click. There, you will see where this class is coming from. Take a note of the file (most probably a jar file) and you'll see it is not the file you are expecting.